# Classes nomeadas com caracteres de emoji

Tags: css, css3, semântica

Estava navegando na `web` e de repente me deparo com isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sim, é uma classe "nomeada" com caracteres de emoji.

Fiquei curioso e decidi realizar alguns testes para ver como funcionava, afinal, não é todo dia que vemos algo parecido.

Resultado:

```css
.{
  color: red;
}
. {
  color: green;
}
# {
  color: blue;
  
}
```

```html
<p class=""> Classe de cor vermelha </p>
<p class=""> Classe de cor verde </p>
<p id=""> Id de cor azul </p>
```

Minha dúvida é:

Nomeando `classes` e `ids` dessa forma, posso ter algum problema? Digo, com incompatibilidade com algum navegador, ou até problema na hora da renderização do `CSS`?

É semântico realizar nomeações assim? E se for casos específicos?

Por exemplo, uma classe apenas para círculos vermelhos:

```css
.{
   background-color: red;
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   border-radius:100%;
   
}
```

```html
<div class=""> </div>
```

Posso realizar a nomeação dessa forma sem correr risco do navegador não reconhecer?